# Search Google Doc Spreadsheet With API

Tags: .net, google-drive-api, spreadsheet

I am brand new to this Drive API and I am looking for Visual Basic .NET example code that shows how to search a Google Doc spreadsheet for a value.

For example lets say I want to search the spreadsheet file located at...
https://docs.google.com/a/XXXX.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Alk;k;z-7X7s-dFBDMGg1bHZnTm9mWmtCUEVzdUR5aHc#gid=0

For the value.....
This is a test

In Column B and if found then return Column D and E of the line in which the value was found.

For the life of me I can not find any good example.

Comment: Sorry this old question didn't get any answers. At some point in the intervening period, the spreadsheet was deleted, so it definitely won't get any answers now. Are you able to edit this, so that it contains a [mcve]?